# Uniformly most powerful test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, neyman-pearson-lemma

Suppose we have Xi~Exp(λ), and we want to construct a most powerful test for

- H0 : λ = λ0, H1 : λ = λ1

I then proceed to use the Neyman Pearson lemma : reject H0 when the likelihood ratio L(λ1;X)/L(λ0;X) is more than k. (Here, I then proceed to use the distriubtio of the sum of Xi, to solve for the quantile and then for k)

Then, the next part of the question asks if the above is the uniformly most powerful test for the following

- H0 : λ ≤ λ0, H1 : λ ≥ λ0

And the given answer is that it is.

Could someone explain to me the connection between the intial case where the hypothesis were simple (therefore just an easy likelihood ratio), and the second case where it is general? How would I answer this question?

Thank you! I have an incomplete understanding of the Neyman Pearson, all I understand is that to find the most powerful test when the hypothesis are simple is to take the likelihood ratio

Comment: In the second case $\lambda$ is a unknown parameter and the distribution of the test statistic depend on it, you have to show that the property of being most powerful holds for all possible values of  $\lambda$ (recall that you know what is the most powerful test for any fixed value of $\lambda$, so think about the relation between it and the test you are using)

Comment: @J.Delaney thank you so much for the help!